# Editing the .profile file to access

Tags: bash, shell-script, java, path, profile

I am trying to source my `.profile` file to easily access a directory of javatools. The bash code below seems like it should work but it does not. Any help troubleshooting this script would be very much appreciated:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/
PATH=$PATH:~/bin

javatools() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $'\nComplete list of tools:'
        ls /Users/username/tools/javatools/
    else
        local toolToRun=/Users/username/tools/javatools/$1
        java -Xmx4g -jar $toolToRun ${@:2}
    fi
}
```

When I source the `.profile` file I receive the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `{'bash: /fise $# java -Xmx4g -jar $toolToRun ${@:2}gs/javatools/$1
```

Without the `javatools` section the `PATH` lines work without issue.

Comment: Are you at any point editing your file using a Windows text editor (ore copying and pasting form a DOS text file)?  It looks like at least some lines may have carriage-returns at the end of them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin

javatools() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $'\nComplete list of tools:'
        ls /Users/username/tools/javatools/
    else
        local toolToRun=/Users/username/tools/javatools/$1
        java -Xmx4g -jar $toolToRun ${@:2}        
}
```